# Trim values of CSV using Notepad++ only if the value is not blank

Tags: regex, csv, notepad++, removing-whitespace

I have the following CSV:

```
COLUMN_A;COLUMN_B;COLUMN_C;COLUMN_D;COLUMN_E;COLUMN_F;COLUMN_G;COLUMN_H;COLUMN_I;COLUMN_L;
01234;AB ;00001; ;100000001;   ;ABC;+0000000000099998,080;XYZ        ;
```

I would like to remove the white spaces only if the value is not blank.
So the result will be like this:

```
COLUMN_A;COLUMN_B;COLUMN_C;COLUMN_D;COLUMN_E;COLUMN_F;COLUMN_G;COLUMN_H;COLUMN_I;COLUMN_L;
01234;AB;00001; ;100000001;   ;ABC;+0000000000099998,080;XYZ;
```

I know that I can use find ' ' replace '' so the space will be replaced by nothing. But in this way, I will remove all the spaces, and I want to maintain the string with spaces where there aren't any other character.

If I have to use regular expression (my first time), I think I need to concatenate the following expression:

```
[a-zA-Z]
[\s]
[;]
```

so I can use [a-zA-Z][\s][;] in the find box,
but I don't know how to replace what it finds with [a-zA-Z][;]

**UPDATE**

The answer of @Trincot is good, but if one of the columns contains for example a description with spaces, these will be deleted

This

COLUMN_A;COLUMN_B;COLUMN_C;

01234;AB;My name is Paul;

will became:

COLUMN_A;COLUMN_B;COLUMN_C;

01234;AB;MynameisPaul;

for that reason, I prefer to capture the last char, all the white spaces and the semicolon

```
([a-zA-Z0-9])([ ]{1,})([;])
```

and replace it with the first and last group

```
$1$3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can distinguish the cases where the string of spaces is not *prefixed* with a semi-colon or white-space, and the cases where the string of spaces is not *suffixed* with a semi-colon or white-space.

For this you can use look-around:

Find what: `\h+(?![;\s])|(?<![;\s])\h+`
Replace with: (empty)
⦿ Regular expression

<kbd>Replace all</kbd>

### Explanation

- `\h` matches a horizontal white-space character (so not newline)
- `(?![;\s])` is a negative look ahead: what follows at the current position should not be one of those characters, but they are not included in the overall match.
- `(?<![;\s])` is a negative look behind: what precedes at the current position should not be one of those characters, but they are not included in the overall match.

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:;|\G(?!^))\K\h*([^\s;]+)\h*(?=[^;]*;)`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:             # non capture group
    ;               # semi-colon
  |               # OR
    \G              # restart from last match position
    (?!^)           # not the beginning of line
)               # end group
\K              # forget all we have seen until this position
\h*             # 0 or more horizontal spaces
(               # group 1
    [^\s;]+         # 1 or more any character that is not a space or semi-colon
)               # end group
\h*             # 0 or more horizontal spaces
(?=             # positive lookahead, make sure we have after:
    [^;]*           # 0 or more any character that is not a semi-colon
    ;               # a semi-colon
)               # end lookahead
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To answer my last question,

It is possible to capture a group by surrounding it with parentheses (round brackets) and each one will be numerated starting from 1, so it will be possible to use them by prefixing the number with a dollar.

In the find box:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9])([ ]{1,})([;])
```

in the replace box

```
$1$3
```

explanation:

> GROUP 1 - ([a-zA-Z0-9])

- capture a char that contains a letter (lower or upper case) or a number

> GROUP 2 - ([ ]{1,})

- capture one or more white spaces

> GROUP 3 - ([;])

- capture the semicolon char.

> $1$3

- Use captured GROUP 1 and 3.